# Return from the calling method

Tags: c#, .net

I have methods

```
public void x()
{
    y();
    z();
}

public void y()
{
    if(some condition) return;
    some code...
}

public void z()
{
    somecode...
}
```

I know that the return statement in `method y()` will be returned without executing anything else in that method if the `somecondition` condition is met and will be returned back to `method x()` and execute the `method z()`. But is there way to return from `method x()` as well without executing `method z()`?

I cant change any constraints or edit `method y`

Comment: cant change the constrains or edit method y().

Comment: Unless you can change `y` you would have to repeat the `if (some condition)` code in either `x` or `z` to make this work. With the code you've shown us there is no other way.

Answer (score 5):

Make `y()` return some kind of code to let `x()` know whether to call `z()` or not.

```
public void x()
{
    if (y())
    {
        z();
    }
}

// Return true if processing should continue.
//
public bool y()
{
    if(some condition) return false;
    some code...
    return true;
}

public void z()
{
    somecode...
}
```

Comment: great.. really appreciable

Comment: thanks for your answer! but i cant change the return type for method y. Sorry, edited my question.

Comment: If you can't change `y()` then there is no easy way to jump out of `x()` it unless `y` already sets something so you know it's been called. You'd have to have the same condition in `x` which is duplicated code and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to return a `bool` value from `y()`.

```
public void x()
{
    var isValidY = y();

    if (isValidY)
        z();
}

public bool y()
{
    if(some condition) return false;

    // some code...
    return true;
}

public void z()
{
    // some code...
}
```

If you can't change `y()` then you'll have to take the advice Enigmativity left in the comments, and repeat the logic represented by `some condition`:

```
public void x()
{
    y();
    if (some condition) return;
    z();
}

public bool y()
{
    if (some condition) return;
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: nice but that extra declaration of `isValidY ` can be avoided.

Comment: sorry about the generic names

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the method signatures, make a global flag variable:

```
private bool shouldContinue = true;

public void x()
{
    y();

    if(shouldContinue)
        z();
}

public void y()
{
    if(some condition)
    {
        shouldContinue = false;
        return;
    }
    some code...
}

public void z()
{
    somecode...
}
```